# I created a next and back option for two iframes. The issue is they both show up when the page loads

Tags: html, iframe

Like the title says, both iframes show up when the page loads. When the page loads, I can click 'back' or 'next' and it goes to one of the iframes. I would prefer if it started out on one specific one.

```
<iframe  src="https://quizlet.com/217817566/match/embed" id="panel11" 
width="1030" height="500"></iframe>
<iframe  src="http://www.c9.io" id="panel10" width="1030" 
height="500"></iframe>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ukk81gs/

Wasn't sure how to post with code because I registered about 15 minutes ago so I threw a jsfiddle up there.

Thanks,

Aaron

P.S. Still fairly new to coding.